# Bass amp combo for open mics and acoustic gigs?

Tags: electric-bass-guitar

I'm buying my first bass amp combo. My band plays in open mics and acoustic gigs. Drummer is playing a cajón.

I'm not looking for a specific model although that would be helpful.

Shopping around, I've noticed these variables seem to affect the price, ranging from quite expensive to very expensive!

1. Total power (W)
2. Woofer size

Eventually we'll move away from acoustic so the drummer will be playing full kit. I think I'll have to buy a much more expensive amp to "compete" with his loudness.

I'm thinking of buying a cheap £80 bass amp for the acoustic gigs and then a much more expensive high-range one (£600+ or however much they cost) for when my drummer goes full kit. I'm worried about falling into a trap of pointlessly buying a more mid-range amp for £300 only to have to buy a high-end one anyway and unnecessarily spending more than I needed to.

1. Is a cheaper bass amp sufficient for acoustic gigs?
2. Is a mid-range bass amp sufficient for full kit gigs?
3. Is there a bass amp you would recommend for an acoustic gig?

Comment: I bought a Fender Rumble 150 (cost about $250 USD) which I use in my practice room, in an auditorium (I play pits) and with my 9-piece band.  150W, 15" woofer.  It also has XLR output to run into the PA if needed, which may be helpful when your drummer ramps up his game.  If I had it to do again, I'd buy a second small practice amp so I didn't have to keep hauling the Fender up and down stairs after each gig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gear recommendation per se is disallowed on this site - so I'll answer in a slightly different way. Over years of playing in all sorts and sizes of bands, I've collected (mostly pre-loved) various bass equipment. For where you describe, I'd be taking a 2x10" speaker cab., and a 150w head. Both easily portable - the 2x10 I knocked up in plywood for next to nothing.

That then means I have other choices of speaker cabs - appropriate to different situations. Bigger gigs get a 1x18" or 1x15" cab, or maybe a 4x10", which is great for a more lively sound. The same head will suffice for any - or I can swap heads for a (second-hand) 350w - maybe too powerful for where you play right now. Or, I can link two cabs together - Summer brought outdoor gigs where the 1x18 and 2x10 worked well together.

So what I recommend is separates rather than a combo, easier to carry, store, and eventually more versatile. Not going to recommend any makes here!

If you have to consider going more than 150w due to a loud drummer, consider a different drummer! Unless you want to end up hearing impaired later in life - which is very much a reality.

Comment: Thanks Tim. After listening to the advice of a few people, including yourself, I've decided to buy a 1x15" lightweight combo to cover all bases. Because it's only 11kg and not too big, I don't think it'll be too much of a pain to carry to smaller events like open mics.

Comment: @JamieButterworth - fine - but don't go underpowered! For 4 string basses 150w is o.k., and it's still o.k. for 5 string, which I play mostly. Although mere wattage doesn't represent volume available - that'll depend on the efficiency of the speaker as well. And a horn/tweeter is nice for bringing out the pops and higher notes/harmonics. Casters help too!